# Node.js API Server - Unable to build

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I'm facing difficulty in create a build of my Node Js API application.

Below is how my package.json file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "node-mongo-registration-login-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "NodeJS + MongoDB API for User Management, Authentication and Registration",
    "main": "server.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./server.js",
        "start-dev": "nodemon ./server.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-jwt": "^5.3.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongodb": "^3.5.6",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
        "rootpath": "^0.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
    }
}
```

When I run **npm run build**, it gives below error:

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\Tejas\Desktop\React\Templates\node-mongo-registration-login-api-master\public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-15T10_12_13_343Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure why an index.html is needed in a server application where no UI is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just implementing API and don't have a react application, you don't need to build it. use `npm run start` to start your server.

Comment: I need to deploy it to heroku which also gives this error when I push it

Comment: I guess you have defined `npm run build` as your start script in heroku too. This command runs your build script which is `react-scripts build` defined in your package json. you don't need it as you don't have a react app. It's better to change your heroku start script to `npm run start` or you can change the build script in package json to: `"build": "npm run start"`

Comment: Thanks. I just removed build line and it worked fine!